# Angular Dynamically Change Component Array Based on Input from User

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel, angular-template

I have a simple search feature [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-course-filter-pipe-mbb53i?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) where users can search for courses.  Users currently have the ability to add search terms e.g. `data`, `probability` which are added to a component property known as `searchTerms`.

I loop through `searchTerms` using `*ngFor` in the view and would like for the user to be able to remove each term by clicking on the `✖` next to the term.  I've defined the `removeTerm()` method as such:

```
removeTerm(term: string){
      var index = this.searchTerms.indexOf('term');
      if (index !== -1) this.searchTerms.splice(index, 1);
      this.filterByTerms();
    }
```

How do I bind each unique query to its own card so that when `removeTerm()` is called, only that term is removed from the `searchTerms` array?  I imagine `ngModel` is necessary to perform two way data-binding, maybe something like `[(ngModel)]='term' (click)="removeTerm(term)"`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pass the index of the card you want to remove like this `(click)="removeTerm(term, index)"`

And then in your controller

```
removeTerm(term: string){
  if (index !== -1) this.searchTerms.splice(index, 1);
  this.filterByTerms();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code, check here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-course-filter-pipe-3mdtgu?file=src/app/app.component.ts

You just need to remove quotes from term:

```
removeTerm(term: string){
      var index = this.searchTerms.indexOf(term);
      if (index !== -1) this.searchTerms.splice(index, 1);
      this.filterByTerms();
    }
```

And add term while calling removeTerm function:

```
<a style="color: indianred; display: inline-block; padding-left: 6px;" (click)="removeTerm(term)">✖</a>
```